# There is a grammatical error in the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have spotted this grammatical error [in the FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site) under *I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?*:

```
3. Is actual code from a project rather then pseudo-code or example code?
     ^ it
```

Small error, but I just noticed it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. It's fixed now.